# Visual Studio Code rulers do not reflect in files (other windows outside of settings.json)

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, cobol, rulers

I have tried to search for a solution, and I haven't found one so far.  I am using VSC for COBOL Linux where ruler settings matter.  Below are the default settings, minus the current ruler sets (8,12,80).  When I change these, they do adjust, but only in the settings window, and do not reflect the change in any other window (Files). Is there something I am missing?

```
    },
    "files.associations": {
        "*.module": "php"
    },
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Enterprise COBOL (for entcobol dialect)",
    "editor.rulers": [
    
    8,12,80]

}
```